# Data getting overwitten in dynamodb aws-api-gateway while using aws service- dynamodb

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

Bodymapping template shown below

[image]

Comment: Avoid link to picture, tell us more about what you are doing, show some code. As it is, I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: Please add more details like code you have written and which scenario/use case the error is happening?